# Significato di "bullo da barriera"

Tags: meaning, regional

Nel racconto *Azoto* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Il cliente sognato era sulla quarantina, piccolo, compatto ed obeso; portava i baffetti alla Clark Gable ed aveva ciuffi di pelo nero un po’ dappertutto, dentro alle orecchie, dentro alle narici, sul dorso delle mani, e sulle falangi fin quasi alle unghie. Era profumato ed impomatato e aveva un aspetto volgare: sembrava un souteneur, o meglio un cattivo attore nella parte del souteneur; oppure un **bullo da barriera**. Mi spiegò che era il proprietario di una fabbrica di cosmetici, ed aveva noie con un certo tipo di rossetto.

Ho ricercato "bullo" su alcuni dizionari, quindi capisco cosa vuol dire. Ho letto anche le [diverse accezioni di "barriera"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/barriera), ma il suo senso nel testo mi è più oscuro. In particolare, non capisco il significato dell'espressione "bullo da barriera" che appare nel brano citato.

Si riferisce forse a una persona con aspetto di bullo che si mette alla porta di qualche stabilmento per selezionare quelli che possono entrare? Magari qualcosa di simile al "buttafuori" di questa [voce del *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI24/GDLI_Supplemento_2009_Pagina_133.jpg)?

Comment: Sì, probabilmente il significato è quello del buttafuori, nel senso che fa da barriera a chi vuole entrare. Non ho trovato altri usi di questa espressione in Google Books. Probabilmente è un modo di dire regionale.

Comment: Potrebbe riferirsi al quartiere popolare “Barriera di Milano” a Torino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Torino esiste il quartiere Barriera di Milano, il cui nome deriva dalla cinta daziaria costruita nel 1853, divenuto poi, in seguito all'industrializzazione, un quartiere popolare e operaio.

In questi quartieri la figura del *bullo* era molto frequente, così come quella del *souteneur* (eufemismo per *lenone*).

È molto probabile che *bullo da barriera* fosse un modo di dire torinese.

Comment: E, infatti, il Treccani spiega che "barriera" usato come nome comune (quindi, scritto con la minuscola) ha questo significato: "per estens., nell’uso region. settentrionale, si dà tradizionalmente il nome di *b.* a quartieri periferici o di circonvallazione". L'espressione non farebbe riferimento a questo quartiere di Torino in particolare, ma alla figura del bullo tipica di questo tipo di quartieri in generale.

Comment: Ne parla il libro [*Piemonte e Val d'Aosta*](https://books.google.es/books?id=yI1oAAAAMAAJ&q=%22di+Stupinigi,+di+Nizza22&dq=%22di+Stupinigi,+di+Nizza%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGjpaLx4nrAhVCzIUKHQQZAfsQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ) di Dino Gribaudi: "L'accesso alla città avveniva in corrispondenza di «barriere», che diedero poi il nome ad altrettante località periferiche: barriere del Regio Parco, di Milano, di Valdocco, di Dora, del Martinetto, di Francia, del Foro Boario, di San Paolo, di Orbassano, di Stupinigi, di Nizza, di Piacenza, di Casale, con le neoclassiche caserme daziarie".